# Merge cil, il and intermediate-language tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The [cil](/questions/tagged/cil), [il](/questions/tagged/il) and [intermediate-language](/questions/tagged/intermediate-language) tags on Stack Overflow all appear to be the same thing to me and none have a wiki describing or distinguishing them.

If I am right, I think they should probably be merged into one tag. If not, then they should probably be given descriptions that distinguish them from each other.

Comment: In retrospect, only il and intermediate-language tags should be merged. cil is a more specific case than the other two.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the [23 questions tagged `il` not obviously about CIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/il+-.net+-cil+-c%23) and only found 3 that weren't about CIL after all ([typo for `<li>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165384/css-ul-li-avoiding-double-borders), [intermediate language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340343/converting-a-cfg-to-il), [RDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728722/what-do-is-il-and-iext-refer-to-in-the-rdf-semantics-specification)). That leaves 211 [il](/questions/tagged/il) questions that are about CIL. My suggestion:

- Merge [il](/questions/tagged/il) into [cil](/questions/tagged/cil) (this is a moderator action).
- Remove the [il](/questions/tagged/il) synonym: [cil](/questions/tagged/cil) is one whole character longer. (Again, this is a moderator action.)

And yes, [intermediate-language](/questions/tagged/intermediate-language) is about the general concept of an intermediate language in compiler design and must be kept separate.

P.S. [intermediate-language](/questions/tagged/intermediate-language) needs a bit of clean up: about 3/4 of the questions are specifically about [cil](/questions/tagged/cil). It's still a useful tag to have.